# Delete "Curriculum" tab from LearnPress plugin (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, learnpress

is there a way to remove/delete the "Curriculum" tab/section from LearnPress plugin?
I can't find a soluction to this problem.

Comment: Have you tried asking the LearnPress support?

Answer (score 2):

You can hide course tab from customize>courses>single Course>sortable tabs>eye icon. Below is the screenshot-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMWLS.png

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the add_filter function mentioned in a previous answer does not work (with this version 4.2.2.2 and probably other versions) on course page (for info, this is the page name of the course: content-single-course.php)

The only setup I would suggest is to play with CSS:

> li:has(> a[href^="#course-instructor"] ) {display: none;}
> li:has(> a[href^="#course-review-rating"] ) {display: none;}

This CSS snippet does not prevent from showing the elements again if you play with inspecting the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'learn-press/course-tabs', 'theme_prefix_lp_course_tab_remove' );

function theme_prefix_lp_course_tab_remove( $tabs ) {
    unset( $tabs['curriculum'] );
    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes